# How to set window.name property from within Http Handler?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I want to set the window.name(JS) property of a window that will invoke the handler code. This property needs to be set from the Http handler code. How to do it?

Comment: I'm a little confused. The Http Handler is server code. It can't manipulate cliente code direclly. What you can do is request to the handler for a name passing some relevant parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize if the description wasn't detailed enough. Actually the handler on successful validation passes the control to a web page. What I did end up implementing was passing a query string parameter when redirecting to a page (alternatively if we're writing the response ourselves then we can directly include the JS block) and have the page's JS check for that query string parameter.